Getting "The profile 'Default' is not found" in the Healthmonitoring section in Web.config when running ASP.NET application
I am running ASP.NET application and face an unexpected runtime error caused by the Healthmonitoring section
<healthMonitoring enabled="true">
  <eventMappings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647"/>
  </eventMappings>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="HealthMonitor_ConnectionString" maxEventDetailsLength="1073741823" buffer="false" name="SqlWebEventProvider" type="System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider"/>
  </providers>
  <rules>
    <clear/>
    <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Errors" provider="SqlWebEventProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00"/>
  </rules>
</healthMonitoring>

When I run the application I get the following error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
specific error details below and modify your configuration file
appropriately.
Parser Error Message: The profile 'Default' is not found.


Everything worked file until it stopped because of the unknown reason. No matter what I try, no matter how many times I would remove the code and get the latest from repository, no matter what I do, I face this error
Please let me know if can suggest any idea
